# Concentration of maximum of subexponential random variables

Tags: self-study, distributions, references, expected-value, probability-inequalities

I'm looking for a concentration bound on the maximum of a collection of sub-exponential random variables, which are not necessarily independent. More specifically, I have the following collection:

\begin{align}
   X_i = |{\langle a^i, u\rangle}|, \; \| u \| = 1, \; a^i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I_d), \; i = 1, \dots, m, \; m \geq d
\end{align}
I want to bound

$$
\max_i X_i \leq \max_i \|a^i\|
$$

and my approach is bounding it via bounding $\max_i \|a^i\|^2$, which is the maximum over the sum of subexponential RVs. When the maximum is over a collection of subgaussians, I am aware of the bound
$
\mathbb{E}[\max_i X_i] = \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{\sigma \log n})$ where $X_i$ are $\sigma$-subgaussian variables, not necessarily independent. Is there something similar for subexponentials (or some easier way of bounding $\max_i \| a^i \|$?)

**Edit:**
Example 2.7 in [1] gives the following bound for $Z_1, \dots, Z_n \sim \chi^2_p$:
$$
\mathbb{E}[\max_i Z_i - p] \leq \sqrt{2 p \log n} + 2 \log n 
$$
so for my case using Markov's inequality I get

$$
\mathbb{P}(\max_i \| a^i \| \leq t) = \mathbb{P}(\max_i \| a^i \|^2 \leq t^2) \geq
1 - \frac{d + 2 \log m + \sqrt{2 d \log m}}{t^2}
$$
which implies that the smallest $t$ for which I can get concentration that increases with the number of measurements $m$ is something like $\sqrt{d \log m}$, which gives me
$$
\mathbb{P}(\max_i \| a^i \| \leq t) \geq 1 - \frac{1}{\log m} - \frac{2}{d} - \sqrt{\frac{2}{d \log m}}
$$

Can I get anything sharper than this?

**Edit 2**: If it helps, we may assume that $a^i$ is a "shifted" version of $a^j$, that is:

$$
\newcommand{\mmod}{\text{ mod }}
a^i = \left( g_{i \mmod m}, g_{i+1 \mmod m}, \dots, g_{i+d-1 \mmod m} \right) \\
a^j = \left( g_{j \mmod m}, g_{j+1 \mmod m}, \dots, g_{j+d-1 \mmod m} \right)
$$
where $g_1, \dots, g_m \overset{\text{i.i.d}}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. In that case, we know that

$$
\max_i \| a^i \| \leq \| g \| \Rightarrow
\mathbb{P}(\max_i X_i \leq \sqrt{m + 1}) \geq 1 - \exp\left(-\frac{m}{8}\right).
$$
where the concentration inequality follows from [[2], Example 2.5](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~mjwain/stat210b/Chap2_TailBounds_Jan22_2015.pdf).
However $\sqrt{m + 1}$ is still too bad of a scaling; I would ideally like something that scales logarithmically in $d$ and $m$. Any help or hints would be welcome.

**Update**: with $\| u \| = 1$, we know that $\langle a^i, u \rangle
\sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \sum_i u_i^2\right) = \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. Additionally $\langle \cdot, u \rangle$ is 1-Lipschitz so we may use the
Gaussian concentration inequality to obtain

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(| \langle a^i, u \rangle| \geq \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}+ t\right) \leq \exp\left(-t^2 / 2 \right), \; \forall i
$$
so setting $ t = \sqrt{2} \log m $ and taking a union bound over the whole set $[m]$
gives me
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\max_i X_i \leq \sqrt{2} \left( \log m + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \right) \right)
\geq 1 - m \exp(-\log^2 m) = 1 - m^{-1}.
$$

**Another attempt**: if we take into account the special structure of the $a^i$'s mentioned above, we can see that

$$
\left| \max_i |\langle a^i, u \rangle| - \max_i | \langle b^i, u \rangle | \right|
\leq \left| \max_i \left( | \langle a^i, u \rangle| - |\langle b^i, u \rangle| \right) \right| \\
\leq \max_i \left| \langle a^i - b^i, u \rangle \right| \leq
\max_i \| a^i - b^i \| \leq \| a - b \|
$$

which shows that $\max_i | \langle a^i, u \rangle|$ is a $1$-Lipschitz function of $g \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I_m)$. This gives

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\left| \max_i X_i - \mathbb{E}(\max_i X_i) \right| \geq t\right)
\leq 2e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}
$$

which gives us

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\max_i X_i \leq c \sqrt{\log m} \right) \geq 1 - m^{-1}
$$

Can we do better than this?

[1]: *Boucheron, Stéphane, Gábor Lugosi, and Pascal Massart. Concentration inequalities: A nonasymptotic theory of independence. Oxford university press, 2013.*

[2]: *Martin J. Wainwright. High Dimensional Statistics: A nonasymptotic viewpoint. Draft edition, 2015.*

Comment: Hint: $|{\langle a, b\rangle}| \le || a|| \, || b ||$. Please add "self-education" tag to your question.